# python matplotlib axis label subscript based on loop counter

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib, label

I'm using python and matplotlib to generate graphical output. 
I am creating multiple plots within a loop and would like the loop counter to serve as an index on the y-axis label. How do I get the loop counter (a variable) to appear as a subscript?

Here's what I have:

`axis_ylabel = plt.ylabel(u"\u03b1 [\u00b0]", rotation='horizontal', position=(0.0,0.9))`

resulting in:

α [°]

(I'm using unicode instead of Tex because dvipng is not available on this system.)

I would like something like this:

```
for i in range(1,3):  
  axis_ylabel = plt.ylabel(u"\u03b1" + str(i) + u" [\u00b0]", rotation='horizontal', position=(0.0,0.9))
```

No surprise, this gives:

α1 [°]
α2 [°]

What I really want is the numbers to be subscripts. How do I combine the conversion to a string with a command to create a subscript? Including a '_' is not recognized in the unicode environment to generate a subscript. Additionally, I still need python/matplotlib to recognize that this subscript-command should affect the following variable.
Any thoughts?

**Edit**

I got this far:

```
axis_ylabel = plt.ylabel(u"\u03b1" + r"$_" + str(i) + r"$" + u" [\u00b0]", rotation='horizontal', position=(0.0,0.9))
```

-- this results in a subscript character. However, it is **NOT** a conversion of the integer value but a different symbol.

**Edit 2**
I am using python 2.6.6 and matplotlib 0.99.1.1. Inserting any kind of string at `<>` in `r"$<>$"` will not result in the display of that string but an entirely different character. I have posted this issue as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733605/python-matplotlib-label-title-wrong-character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib ships its own mathematical expression engine, called `mathtext`.
From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#subscripts-and-superscripts):

> Note that you do not need to have TeX installed, since matplotlib
>   ships its own TeX expression parser, layout engine and fonts.

So maybe try to use the following:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    plt.ylabel(
           r"$\alpha_{:d} [\degree]$".format(i),
           rotation='horizontal',
           position=(0.0,0.9))
```

You can also use Unicode in `mathtext`:

> If a particular symbol does not have a name (as is true of many of the
>   more obscure symbols in the STIX fonts), Unicode characters can also
>   be used:

```
 ur'$\u23ce$'
```

Comment: @Schorsch I cannot comprehend -- the code above works fine for me and your error report has nothing to do with matplotlib. Please post your code.

Comment: @Schorsch actually you should not be required to use unicode when mathtext works for you -- `r'$\alpha_2 [\degree]$'` should work -- note that `\alpha` is only interpreted inside `$...$`. If the format-syntax doesn't work, try the old syntax: `r'$\alpha_%d [\degree]$' % i`