# python matplotlib label/title wrong character

Tags: python, character-encoding, matplotlib, label

This is a partial cross-post to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712292/python-matplotlib-axis-label-subscript-based-on-loop-counter).
Here is a minimal example of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
y = [7.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 0.0]

II = 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)

# un-comment title as needed:
#plot_title = r"A$_" + str(II) + r"$"
#plot_title = "A$_" + str(II) + "$"
plot_title = (r"A$_%s$" % (str(II)))
print plot_title
plt.title(plot_title)
plt.show()
```

There are three different versions of the same plot-title-string. The `print plot_title` above gives the correct raw string for each case:

```
A$_2$
```

However, none of those approaches shows the correct string in the figure (independent of the back-end I use). The output in the figure  reveals this relation between the input integer value and the output:

```
$0$ -> E  
$1$ -> £  
$2$ -> N  
$3$ -> ®  
$4$ -> X  
$5$ -> ¸(cedille)  
$6$ -> b  
$7$ -> ¿  
$8$ -> j  
$9$ -> 3
```

I am using python 2.6.6 and matplotlib 0.99.1.1 -- I have no control over these versions and will have to do with them.
How should I change my input to get the desired output?

**Edit**

Inspired by [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635293/unicode-character-render) I tried all the different fonts my system knows:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager  

for i in range(0,len(sorted(font_manager.findSystemFonts()))):
    plt.rcParams['font.family'] = os.path.basename(sorted(font_manager.findSystemFonts())[i])[:-4]
```

And generated a plot for each font and the above example. While I got different fonts for the text, the one subscript I care about, `$_2$`, did not change and was always shown as *`N`*.

**EDIT 2**
I have upgraded to matplotlib 1.3.0 and the issue is gone. This leaves me thinking it had to do with version 0.99.1.1
To me, this is still not satisfactory, because I would have liked to know *why* it was behaving in this way.

**EDIT 3**
I came across this question: [Superscript in Python plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226868/superscript-in-python-plots)
The answer suggests that the issue may arise from using `A$_2$` instead of `$A_2$`.
Unfortunately, this did not change the output in this case.

Comment: Are you using the above mark-up because you are trying to use LaTeX in your figure title?  If this is the case, have you tried `rc('text', usetex=True)` at the beginning of your code to specify LaTeX in the output?

Comment: @cosmosis: I'm not necessarily in need of Latex, I just need some greek letters and subscripts. Being a long-time LaTex user, that syntax is easy to me. I tried `rc('text', usetex=True)` but something in the setup on this network isn't working properly because it generates a lot of errors. Unfortunately the mathtype doesn't really work either (see 'cross-post' link at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using matplotlib version 1.3.1 and python version 2.7.8.
I was having a similar problem. I was writing

```
ax1.set_yticklabels(['$10^4$','$10^5$','$10^6']$'
```

The 1 would render as a phi symbol. The 0 would render as E. The 4 would render as a Xi... so on.

I was able to 'fix' it by using `'$\mathregular{10}^\mathregular{4}$'` which is kind of cumbersome but it does the job.

Comment: Even though I am not one bit smarter *why* this occurs, it actually solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. This minimal example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
subplot( 111, title=r"$\mathcal{O}\left( N^3 \right)$" )
show()
```

was rendered to:

[image]

Adding `matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)` at the beginning solved the problem for me:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
subplot( 111, title=r"$\mathcal{O}\left( N^3 \right)$" )
show()
```

[image]

This line makes matplotlib use LaTeX instead of the internal [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial) engine, which seems to be a subset of LaTeX, although superscripts should still work. Using LaTeX requires a working LaTeX installation, as well as dvipng and ghostscript, also it is slower. So this solution might only be worth trying if you have these prerequisites installed anyway.

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6976).

After some time-costly tests I found out, that downgrading from `fonts-lyx 2.2.0-2` to `2.1.4-2` also solved the problem for me. `fonts-lyx` is a dependency of `python-matplotlib-data`, but no specific version is specified, resulting in this problem. Although I don't have enough techical knowledge to be able to say what changes to a font are incompatibel with programs using it.