# Unicode character render

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't find a way to render the unicode characters in the matlibplot chart:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal
from itertools import count
import matplotlib
a = {u'\u043f\u0430\u0440\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0430': 0.018144370928201092, u'\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0447\u043a\u0430\u0442\u0430': 0.008406336989671147, u'\u043d\u0430\u043e\u0453\u0430': 0.0704839024518581, u'\u0444\u0438\u0437\u0438\u043a\u0430': 0.025219010969013446, u'\u043a\u043e\u0438': 0.0039908251856718025, u'\u0438\u0437\u0431\u0443\u0432\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0430': 0.0035792606713834184, u'\u043c\u0435\u0445\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430\u0442\u0430': 0.008406336989671147, u'\u043c\u0438\u043a\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0437\u0438\u0438': 0.008406336989671147, u'\u0434\u0430\u0432\u0430': 0.016812673979342295, u'\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430': 0.008406336989671147}

plt.bar(*zip(*zip(count(), a.values())))
plt.title("Some chart")
plt.xticks(*zip(*zip(count(0.4), (a.keys()))))
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a font with Cyrillic characters. For example,

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
```

Your default font might be `'Helvetica'`, which does not have glyphs for the required characters.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal
from itertools import count
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
a = {u'\u043f\u0430\u0440\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0430': 0.018144370928201092, u'\u0440\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0432\u0438\u0442\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0447\u043a\u0430\u0442\u0430': 0.008406336989671147, u'\u043d\u0430\u043e\u0453\u0430': 0.0704839024518581, u'\u0444\u0438\u0437\u0438\u043a\u0430': 0.025219010969013446, u'\u043a\u043e\u0438': 0.0039908251856718025, u'\u0438\u0437\u0431\u0443\u0432\u043d\u0430\u043b\u0430': 0.0035792606713834184, u'\u043c\u0435\u0445\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043a\u0430\u0442\u0430': 0.008406336989671147, u'\u043c\u0438\u043a\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0437\u0438\u0438': 0.008406336989671147, u'\u0434\u0430\u0432\u0430': 0.016812673979342295, u'\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430': 0.008406336989671147}

plt.bar(*zip(*zip(count(), a.values())))
plt.title("Gaussian Histogram")
plt.xticks(*zip(*zip(count(0.4), a.keys())))
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you don't have the `Arial` font, you can generate a list of font files known to your system with

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
print(sorted(font_manager.findSystemFonts()))
```

You can then try out the fonts using

```
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()
```

where `path` is one of the paths returned by `findSystemFonts()`.

Comment: i get the following error: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Arial'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: even after using the above functions still getting the same error :(

Comment: I have solved the problem also with removing the content from the cache of the library sudo gedit  ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache