# How can I dynamically choose an appropriate font in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, unicode, fonts

I want to plot points with text labels where the text comes from a variety of different languages and alphabets. Using the default font, only certain characters can be displayed and others are printed as boxes. Is it possible to automatically figure out if a given font supports the unicode characters that I want to print? Is there a single font that can support all of the characters?

Some [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635293/unicode-character-render) address the problem of changing the font when the desired character set is known, e.g. Cyrillic. My problem is that I need to support all sorts of different character sets.

Comment: probably, and yes, in that order, but before we get into that it's important to point out that you *are* [expected to first search for answers to this question yourself](/help/how-to-ask), as Stackoverflow is mostly here for questions around code that you've written to solve your problem, but the code isn't doing what you expect it to do. What have you searched/found so far, and how did that not help address your problem?

Comment: I can't find any existing questions that cover the issue of dynamically identifying a font that is capable of rendering a given unicode character. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: right, so... google? matplotlib has its own site and community, you sure that information isn't somewhere on http://matplotlib.org/?