# Superscript in Python plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to label my x axis at follows :

```
pylab.xlabel('metres 10^1')
```

But I don't want to have the ^ symbol included .

```
pylab.xlabel('metres 10$^{one}$')
```

This method works and will superscript letters but doesn't seem to work for numbers .
If I try :

```
pylab.xlabel('metres 10$^1$')
```

It superscripts a letter N for some reason .

Anyone know how to superscript numbers in python plots ?
thanks .

Comment: Try to remove the curly braces as they are superfluous when superscripting only one character.

Comment: You are right , the curly braces were superfluous , but unfortunately I still end up with a letter N instead of the number 1 .

Comment: Sounds like you're missing some fonts? I guess using `rc('text', usetex=True)` works?

Comment: @Jakob . Excuse my ignorance but how exactly do I implement that ? Where do I type it ?

Comment: Try `from matplotlib import rc` and `rc('text', usetex=True)` see http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/usetex.html

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You just need to have the full expression inside the `$`.  Basically, you need `"meters $10^1$"`.  You don't need `usetex=True` to do this (or most any mathematical formula).

You may also want to use a raw string (e.g. `r"\t"`, vs `"\t"`) to avoid problems with things like `\n`, `\a`, `\b`, `\t`, `\f`, etc.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title=r'This is an expression $e^{\sin(\omega\phi)}$',
       xlabel='meters $10^1$', ylabel=r'Hertz $(\frac{1}{s})$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you don't want the superscripted text to be in a different font than the rest of the text, use `\mathregular` (or equivalently `\mathdefault`). Some symbols won't be available, but most will.  This is especially useful for simple superscripts like yours, where you want the expression to blend in with the rest of the text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title=r'This is an expression $\mathregular{e^{\sin(\omega\phi)}}$',
       xlabel='meters $\mathregular{10^1}$',
       ylabel=r'Hertz $\mathregular{(\frac{1}{s})}$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

For more information (and a general overview of matplotlib's "mathtext"), see: http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively, in python 3.6+, you can [generate Unicode superscript](https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator) and copy paste that in your code:

```py
ax1.set_ylabel('Rate (min⁻¹)')
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write  unit `per meter (m^-1)`, use `$m^{-1}$)`, which means `-1` inbetween `{}`

Example:
`plt.ylabel("Specific Storage Values ($m^{-1}$)", fontsize = 12 )`

Comment: This makes it italicized, which is undesirable for units.

Comment: How can we make it like normal text, specially with negative power?

Comment: try wrapping the text you want to look normal in `\mathrm{}`

Comment: Use same as @JoeKington answer but with additional brackets xlabel='meters $\mathregular{10^{-1}}$',