# Can python plot power characters?

Tags: python, plot

[image: m^2 -> m2]

Can python plot power characters like this image??

i just want matplotlib.pyplot plt image looks more good.

Comment: Use: `'$m^{2}$'`.

Comment: It works very good, Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Superscript in Python plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226868/superscript-in-python-plots)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass LaTeX styled strings to pyplot by wrapping them in dollar signs.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(0.5, 0.5, '$m^{2}$')
plt.show()
```